# Create an external file for side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, include

How do I create an external file for my side menu?

```html
<a class="active" href="C.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">C Programming</a>
<a href="C++.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">C++</a>
<a href="CSharp.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">C#</a>
<a href="Go.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">Go</a>
<a href="Java.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">Java</a>
<a href="JavaScript.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">JavaScript</a>
<a href="PHP.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">PHP</a>
<a href="Python.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">Python</a>
<a href="Ruby.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">Ruby</a>
<a href="Swift.html" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">Swift</a>
```

Currently I have these kind of links in every file and the code is just getting too much. Is there a way to create an external file for the menu items?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8988855/519413) but the problem is `class="active"`. I want to highlight a menu item when my menu item is in index.php
I Know how to achieve this when my menu is in each individual HTML file but how do I do that when it's in external PHP file ?

Index.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Tags.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Nav.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Card.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Buttons.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="sidenav">

 <h1>&nbspOthers</h1>
 <a href="" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">MS Excel</a>
 <a href="" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">MS PowerPoint</a>
 <a href="" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">MS Word</a>
 <a href="" style="font-size: 1.1em;font-weight: 900;">WordPress</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Main file

```
<?php include('index.html'); ?>
```

Comment: Don't use JS to include static content from another page (as it makes an extra request to the server). Instead you should be able to 'include' the content on the server before the HTML is sent to the browser. Exactly how you do that depends on what type of server you're using, and the technologies it supports.

Comment: Well im hosting it on my own right now. ill probably shift to a server if i get enough traffic @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I have several questions : Are you files `.html` or `.php` files ? The naming of your file is not clear, your main file includes `index.html` and your other file is `index.php`. Do you have a PHP interpreter (like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/)) installed on the server/computer hosting your website ? PHP code inside a PHP file won't be interpreted if the hosting machine doesn't have a PHP interpreter

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use javascript to include your menu . 
you can use PHP to simply include your menu ( but i sugget header ) file to your page :

`<?php include('/template/header.html'); ?>`

or you can use pre processors like [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) :

`@@include('./template/header.html')`

```
var fileinclude = require('gulp-file-include'),
gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('fileinclude', function() {
  gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

or [Pug](https://pugjs.org/) or [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) and ......

---

About your problem in comments . lets say you are in your main folder and you have this 3 files :

```
index.php
header.html
homepage.html
footer.html
```

`index.php` should be like this :

```
<?php
include('header.html');
include('hompage.html');
include('footer.html');
?>
```

and then in your browsers you should open index.php .

** don't use index.html and index.php in the same time .

if it didn't work . you should get error in your `index.php` file .

when your code works . i suggest you to use [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of include . if your another files are just html and not have any php codes in it .

Comment: For some reason PHP include doesnt work. Should i install some additional plugin for implementing php or something in my .html code?

Comment: @HaileyAsh do you get any errors ? is your main file ( for example : index.php ) in the same directory as your header.html file ?

Comment: change the extension of `index.html` to `index.php` , then use the php code inside this file .

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Abolfazl Ghaemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4949062/abolfazl-ghaemi) :

> You should NOT use javascript to include your menu . you can use PHP to simply include your menu ( but i sugget header ) file to your page :
>
> ```
> <?php include('/template/header.html'); ?>
> ```

The [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/)/[Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) solution is fine but I'll stick with the `<?php include(); ?>` solution for your problem.

### Does the hosting machine speak PHP ?

If browsers can read HTML just fine to give you a webpage, they can't read PHP. Instead, PHP need to be executed by something on the hosting machine and you will need a PHP interpreter for that like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/).

If you didn't already, I strongly recommend you to [install it](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html) or even a full [AMP stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache%E2%80%93MySQL%E2%80%93PHP_packages).

### PHP in HTML files won't work

You need to make sure your file using PHP instructions are `.php` files. Otherwise, the code in your `<?php ?>` tag (the PHP code) won't be interpreted at all.

Make sure your main file is a `.php` file.

### Are you calling the correct file ?

Also, you need to be sure the file name you are including is correct. The content as shown in your question is

> Main file
>
> ```
> <?php include('index.html'); ?>
> ```

but your file is actually `index.php` not `index.html`.

### HTML is prettier with CSS

If you want to "highlight" the item with `active` class, you will need CSS. You can quickly add CSS in your file with a `<style>` tag. See the example below.

```html
<ul>
<li>Not highlighted</li>
<li>Still not highlighted</li>
<li class="active">Highlighted ! Spotlight's on me baby !</li>
<li>Not highlighted</li>
</ul>

<style>
.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ok making php work isnt a big deal. But as i mentioned in the question how do i get a certain menu to be highlighted

Comment: My bad, didn't see that part :) You'll achieve this by adding CSS on the `active` class. You can quickly add CSS code in your file in a `<style>` tag. I'll edit my answer to cover that part.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. See i have 10 files with the same menu. When im in Page A i want A in the menu to be highlighted. When im in Page B i want B to be highlighted. i can easily achieve this with adding code in each html file. My question is how do i use an external include file where i place my menu and achieve this

Comment: Ok, I think I got it : You want to include the "menu" file in all your other pages and you want that "menu" file to auto-highlight the link corresponding to your current page. Is that it ?